# Сдюжить и дюжина

Tags: этимология, однокоренные-слова

Вопрос о числительное (в том числе о слове "дюжина") натолкнул на мысль: а являются ли родственными слова "дюжина", то есть 12, и "сдюжить", "недюженный"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Родственными - нет. Но, по Фасмеру, возможно "народное" сближение, т.е. окончательный облик слова "дюжина" оформился под влиянием "дюжить".